# Countable union of relatively compact sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal K(X)$ be $\sigma$-algebra, generated by compacts of $X$. Prove that for any set $B \in \mathcal K(X)$ either $B$ or its complement can be represented as a countable union of relatively compact sets.

My attempt: Let $B\in K(X)$ be a proper subset of $X$. Since $B \in \mathcal K(X)$ either it is a countable union of compact sets or its complement is such. Since all compact sets are relatively compact, we're done.

So the whole question is if $X$ can be represented as a countable union of relatively compact sets. And I'm stuck on this. Could you help me?

Comment: An infinite-dimensional Banach space cannot be written as a countable union of relatively compact (aka precompact) sets. Indeed, the closures of such sets have empty interior, hence the union is of 1st category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\mathcal{K}(X)$ is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra which contains the compacts.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the collection of all sets $A \subset X$ such that either $A$ or its complement $A^C$ is a countable union of relatively compact sets. Obviously $\mathcal{A}$ contains the compacts so, if $\mathcal{A}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathcal{K}(X) \subset \mathcal{A}$ must hold.

- It is obvious that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complementation.
- Suppose $A_1,A_2,A_3\ldots \in \mathcal{A}$. If one of their complements, say $A_1^C$, can be expressed as a countable union of relatively compact sets, then so too can  $\left( \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)^C = \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i^C$ (why?). Otherwise, one must have that $A_i$ is a countable union of relatively compact sets for each $i$. In this case $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ can also be expressed in this form (why?).

Comment: Thank you for the nice solution, I was thinking about this question. If $A_1^C$ can be expressed as $\bigcup_nU_n$, where the $(U_n)$ are relatively compact, then $\left(\bigcup_iA_i\right)^C=\bigcup_n\left(U_n\bigcap_{i\ge2}A_i^C\right)$. In order for this to be a union of relatively compact sets, don't we need $X$ to be Hausdorff? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Never mind, a closed subset of a compact set is always compact. Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. By the way, this is a fairly common strategy for showing every element of a $\sigma$-algebra has some property: (1) show the generators of your sigma algebra have the property, (2) show the set of sets having the desired property is itself a $\sigma$-algebra.